# Why does odataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxPartsPerBatch not work?

Tags: odata

I'm using Odata v4 to build web api service.When I need to insert more than 100 queries to a batch,my service will return 500 and "ExceptionMessage":"The current batch message contains too many parts. A maximum number of '100' query operations and change sets are allowed in a batch message."

I added these code below but it still not work:

```
        odataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxOperationsPerChangeset = 10000;
        odataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxPartsPerBatch = 10000;
```

What can i do ? thanks

Comment: Any body knows?

Comment: Got the same problem. Were you able to solve this? Seems pretty basic, but unfortunately it doesn't work.