# Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException: A maximum number of 1000 operations are allowed in a change set

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

As the title says. I am having trouble fixing the above error when inserting more than a thousand records in an OData batch process using [Simple OData Client. 4.29.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Simple.OData.Client/)

I have the same problem with the guy from [MaxOperationsPerChangeset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537553/why-does-odatabatchhandler-messagequotas-maxpartsperbatch-not-work) except that I'm only using OData V3. It remains unanswered for the past 7 months, so I'm trying my luck in case someone knew how to fix this but missed the old thread. I tried setting up both MaxOperationsPerChangeset and MaxPartsPerBatch in my OData Service as follows.

```
ODataBatchHandler _batchHandler = new EntityFrameworkBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);
        _batchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxOperationsPerChangeset = Int32.MaxValue;
        _batchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxPartsPerBatch = Int32.MaxValue;
       
        conventions.Insert(0, new CompositeKeyRouting());
       
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "odata", 
            routePrefix : null, 
            model: GetModel(),
            pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
            batchHandler : _batchHandler,
            routingConventions: conventions);
```

And in my Simple OData Client I have this code

```
 stkmupdateBatch += c => c
        .For<stockmovement>()
        .Filter(f => f.StoreCode == stkm.StoreCode && f.Refno == stkm.Refno)
        .DeleteEntriesAsync();

   IEnumerable<stockmovement> _movements = stockmovementClient.Where(s => s.StoreCode == stkm.StoreCode && s.Refno == stkm.Refno);
   //6,140 records...
   foreach (stockmovement stkmi in _movements)
   {
        stkmi.Migration = 0;
        stkmupdateBatch += c => c
           .For<stockmovement>()
           .Set(stkmi)
           .InsertEntryAsync();
   }

   try
   {
         await stkmupdateBatch.ExecuteAsync();
         success = true;
   }
```

I read from [Microsoft Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8efd4abf-9226-4ec9-b54b-50667a64db6d/exception-a-maximum-number-of-1000-operations-are-allowed-in-a-change-set?forum=adodotnetdataservices) that they have fixed this error so I don't really know why I'm experiencing this problem.

Please note that EntityFrameworkBatchHandler is an extension of DefaultODataBatchHandler which I have downloaded from [EntityFrameworkBatchHandler](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/WebApi/v3/ODataEFBatchSample/ODataEFBatchSample/Extensions/EntityFrameworkBatchHandler.cs)

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess I'm going to suffer the same fate as the guy from the old post. I'm actually hoping that someone would at least confirm that this is still a limitation in the  batch process or give an alternative solution? How I wish I have more reputations so that I can offer it to someone/somebody who would be able to put some effort and make a suggestions. I don't really want to believe that this is a hopeless case. Could be simple for the stockoverflow's experts and gurus.

Comment: No one knows? nor can confirm this limitation? Or can point me to the right direction?